# Mongo db showing record after deleting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an Angular on the frontend with node on the backend, where I show user messages that a user can delete and edit.
When I am deleting a message I also remove all the records from the users array of messages, and on the frontend that works fine, no messages that were deleted show up, but when I check in the DB, for user records, there is still one recored in the messages array of a user.

So, when I do `db.users.find()`

I get for the user that has all messages deleted:

```
"messages" : [ ObjectId("58d921cacca7c04abd100344") ], "__v" : 9
```

This is the `messages model` where I pull the message record on delete from the DB.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = require('./user');

var schema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

schema.post('remove', function (message) {
    User.findById(message.user, function (err, user) {
        user.messages.pull(message);
        user.save();
    });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

And this is the `user model`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    messages: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

When I check the messages collection, there are no messages there at all. 
Though it works fine on the frontend, I wonder why is it still showing that record in the DB, when all the messages have been deleted for the user?

Comment: Can you output `message` value to the log for the  remove function ? J

Comment: Can you please show us your User Model declaration

Comment: @JulienTASSIN I have added the user model to the question

Comment: I think that you must have an error in `user.save()`. To be sure, add an error handling after `.save` : user.save(error => {console.error(error);})`